# GitLab CI rules not working with extends and individual rules

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Below are two jobs in the build stage.
Default, there is set some common condition, and using extends keyword for that, `ifawsdeploy`.
As only one of them should run, if variable `$ADMIN_SERVER_IP` provided then connect_admin_server should run, working that way.
If no value provided to `$ADMIN_SERVER_IP` then `create_admin_server` should run, but it is not running.

```
.ifawsdeploy:
  rules:
    - if: '$TEST_CREATE_ADMIN && $REGION && $ROLE_ARN && $PACKAGEURL && $TEST_CREATE_ADMIN == "aws" && $SUB_PLATFORM == "aws" && $ROLE_ARN != "" && $PACKAGEURL != "" && $REGION != ""'

variables:
 TEST_CREATE_ADMIN:
   #value: aws
   description: "Platform, currently aws only"
 SUB_PLATFORM:
   value: aws
   description: "Platform, currently aws only"
 REGION:
   value: "us-west-2"
   description: "region where to deploy company"
 PACKAGEURL:
   value: "http://somerpmurl.x86_64.rpm"
   description: "company rpm file url"
 ACCOUNT_NAME:
   value: "testsubaccount"
   description: "Account name of sub account to refer in the deployment, no need to match in AWS"
 ROLE_ARN:
   value: "arn:aws:iam::491483064167:role/uat"
   description: "ROLE ARN of the user account assuming: aws sts get-caller-identity"
 tfenv_version: "1.1.9"
 DEV_PUB_KEY:
   description: "Optional public key file to add access to admin server" 
 ADMIN_SERVER_IP:
   description: "Existing Admin Server IP Address"
 ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY:
   description: "Existing Admin Server SSH_KEY PEM content"
  
#export variables below will cause the terraform to use the root account instead of the one specified in tfvars file
.configure_aws_cli: &configure_aws_cli
    - aws configure set region $REGION
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_FULL_STS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_FULL_STS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET
    - aws sts get-caller-identity
    - aws configure set source_profile default --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME
    - aws configure set role_arn $ROLE_ARN --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME
    - aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME
    - aws configure set region $REGION --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME

.copy_remote_log: &copy_remote_log
- if [ -e outfile ]; then rm outfile; fi
- copy_command="$(cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/scp_command.txt)"
- new_copy_command=${copy_command/"%s"/"outfile"}
- new_copy_command=${new_copy_command/"~"/"/home/ec2-user/outfile"}
- echo $new_copy_command
- new_copy_command=$(echo "$new_copy_command" | sed s'/\([^.]*\.[^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\1 \3 \2/')
- echo $new_copy_command
- sleep 10
- eval $new_copy_command

.check_remote_log: &check_remote_log
- sleep 10
- grep Error outfile || true
- sleep 10
- returnCode=$(grep -c Error outfile) || true
- echo "Return code received $returnCode"
- if [ $returnCode -ge 1 ]; then exit 1; fi
- echo "No errors"

.prepare_ssh_key: &prepare_ssh_key
- echo $ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_key.pem
- cat ssh_key.pem
- sed -i -e 's/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/-bk-/g' ssh_key.pem
- sed -i -e 's/-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/-ek-/g' ssh_key.pem
- perl -p -i -e 's/\s/\n/g' ssh_key.pem
- sed -i -e 's/-bk-/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/g' ssh_key.pem
- sed -i -e 's/-ek-/-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/g' ssh_key.pem
- cat ssh_key.pem
- chmod 400 ssh_key.pem

connect-admin-server:
  stage: build
  allow_failure: true
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [ "" ]
  rules:
    - if: '$ADMIN_SERVER_IP && $ADMIN_SERVER_IP != "" && $ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY && $ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY != ""'
  extends:
    - .ifawsdeploy
  script:
    - TF_IN_AUTOMATION=true
    - yum update -y
    - yum install git unzip gettext jq -y
    - echo "Your admin server key and info are added as artifacts"
    # Copy the important terraform outputs to files for artifacts to pass into other jobs
    - *prepare_ssh_key
    - echo "ssh -i ssh_key.pem ec2-user@${ADMIN_SERVER_IP}" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_command.txt
    - echo "scp -q -i ssh_key.pem %s ec2-user@${ADMIN_SERVER_IP}:~" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/scp_command.txt
    - test_pre_command="$(cat "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_command.txt") -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    - echo $test_pre_command
    - test_command="$(echo $test_pre_command | sed -r 's/(ssh )(.*)/\1-tt \2/')"
    - echo $test_command
    - echo "sudo yum install -yq $PACKAGEURL 2>&1 | tee outfile ; exit 0" | $test_command
    - *copy_remote_log
    - echo "Now checking log file for returnCode"
    - *check_remote_log
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    when: always
    paths:
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_key.pem"
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_command.txt"
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/scp_command.txt"
  after_script:
    - cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_key.pem
    - cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_command.txt
    - cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/scp_command.txt

create-admin-server:
  stage: build
  allow_failure: false
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [ "" ]
  rules:
    - if: '$ADMIN_SERVER_IP != ""'
      when: never
  extends:
    - .ifawsdeploy
  script:
    - echo "admin server $ADMIN_SERVER_IP"
    - TF_IN_AUTOMATION=true
    - yum update -y
    - yum install git unzip gettext jq -y
    - *configure_aws_cli
    - aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME #to check whether updated correctly or not
    - git clone "https://project-n-setup:$(echo $PERSONAL_GITLAB_TOKEN)@gitlab.com/company-oss/project-n-setup.git"
    # Install tfenv
    - git clone https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv.git ~/.tfenv
    - ln -s ~/.tfenv /root/.tfenv
    - ln -s ~/.tfenv/bin/* /usr/local/bin
    # Install terraform 1.1.9 through tfenv
    - tfenv install $tfenv_version
    - tfenv use $tfenv_version
    # Copy the tfvars temp file to the terraform setup directory
    - cp .gitlab/admin_server.temp_tfvars project-n-setup/$SUB_PLATFORM/
    - cd project-n-setup/$SUB_PLATFORM/
    - envsubst < admin_server.temp_tfvars > admin_server.tfvars
    - rm -rf .terraform || exit 0
    - cat ~/.aws/config
    - terraform init -input=false
    - terraform apply -var-file=admin_server.tfvars -input=false -auto-approve
    - echo "Your admin server key and info are added as artifacts"
    # Copy the important terraform outputs to files for artifacts to pass into other jobs
    - terraform output -raw ssh_key > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_key.pem
    - terraform output -raw ssh_command > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_command.txt
    - terraform output -raw scp_command > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/scp_command.txt
    - cp $CI_PROJECT_DIR/project-n-setup/$SUB_PLATFORM/terraform.tfstate $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - cp $CI_PROJECT_DIR/project-n-setup/$SUB_PLATFORM/admin_server.tfvars $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_key.pem"
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/ssh_command.txt"
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/scp_command.txt"
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/terraform.tfstate"
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/admin_server.tfvars"
```

How to fix that?

I tried the below step from suggestions on comments section.

```
.generalgrabclustertrigger:
  rules:
    - if: '$TEST_CREATE_ADMIN && $REGION && $ROLE_ARN && $PACKAGEURL && $TEST_CREATE_ADMIN == "aws" && $SUB_PLATFORM == "aws" && $ROLE_ARN != "" && $PACKAGEURL != "" && $REGION != ""'

.ifteardownordestroy:  # Automatic if triggered from gitlab api AND destroy variable is set
  rules:
    - !reference [.generalgrabclustertrigger, rules]
    - if: 'CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "triggered"'
      when: never
```

And included the above in extends of a job.

```
destroy-admin-server:
  stage: cleanup
  extends:
    - .ifteardownordestroy
  allow_failure: true
  interruptible: false
```

But I am getting syntax error in the .ifteardownordestroy part.

> jobs:destroy-admin-server:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax

Answer (score 4):

You are overriding `rules:` in your job that extends `.ifawsdeploy`. `rules:` are not combined in this case -- the definition of `rules:` in the job takes complete precedence.

Take for example the following configuration:

```
.template:
  rules:
    - one
    - two

myjob:
  extends: .template
  rules:
    - a
    - b
```

In the above example, the `myjob` job only has rules `a` and `b` in effect. Rules `one` and `two` are completely ignored because they are overridden in the job configuration.

Instead of uinsg `extends:`, you can use `!reference` to preserve and combine rules. You can also use YAML anchors if you want.

```
create-admin-server:
  rules:
    - !reference [.ifawsdeploy, rules]
    - ... # your additional rules
```

> If no value provided to $ADMIN_SERVER_IP then create_admin_server should run

Lastly, pay special attention to your rules:

```
  rules:
    - if: '$ADMIN_SERVER_IP != ""'
      when: never
```

In this case, there are no rules that allow the job to run ever. You either need a case that will evaluate true for the job to run, or to have a default case (an item with no `if:` condition) in order for the job to run.

To get the behavior you expect, you probably want your default case to be `on_success`:

```
  rules:
    - if: '$ADMIN_SERVER_IP != ""'
      when: never
    - when: on_success
```

Comment: I tried your step but failing with syntax, can you please check the details added above

Comment: @Jor-El lists are not valid for the `extends:` keyword -- it must be a string. That's probably your validation error.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your rules to :

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: '$ADMIN_SERVER_IP != ""'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

or

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: '$ADMIN_SERVER_IP == ""'
      when: always
```

I have a sample in here: [try-rules-stackoverflow-72545625 - GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/blob/try-rules-stackoverflow-72545625/.gitlab-ci.yml) and the pipeline record [Pipeline no value - GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/pipelines/558761246), [Pipeline has value - GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/pipelines/558763222)

Comment: You copied the same lines I mentioned, what is the difference?
And my issue is with using both extending rules and normal rules, kindly go through the question once again

Comment: GitLab CI .gitlab-ci.yml rules

> Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated in order until the first match.

means "no rules match will no job create"


[`.gitlab-ci.yml` keyword reference | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)

Comment: your pipelines are not accessible, and I didn't understand what you are trying to say, could you please elaborate please. You mean to say extends keyword rules won't work?

Comment: sorry, I opened the GitLab repo.

rules extend will be overwritten. you can use GitLab Pipeline Editor to see "View merged YAML".

Comment: in my sample 5 job. no rules, so .rules_extend_has_value extend. and sample 4 job has rules, so rules are overwritten.